# Batch Script to find what port Apache Tomcat is running on

Tags: apache, tomcat, batch-file

Pretty close on solving this one.

```
SET settings=D:\tomcat\conf\server.xml
FOR /F "eol=p tokens=1-2* delims==" %%A IN ('TYPE %settings% 2^> NUL ^| FINDSTR.exe /L /C:"\<Connector port\="') DO echo %%B

pause
```

Apache Tomcat typically runs on port 80 in our Test/Prod/QA/Environments, but we have a couple instances that are on port 8080 and want parse out the port to be 100% accurate.

Here are the results:

```
D:\WORK\Scripts\test>echo "80" protocol
"80" protocol

D:\WORK\Scripts\test>echo "8443" protocol
"8443" protocol

D:\WORK\Scripts\test>echo "8009" protocol
"8009" protocol
```

Looking at the server.xml, we have (the first one is correct):

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

as well as (had to remove the comments for posting) - and is commented to turn "off":

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

and:

Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

And..  Here is the finalized code to show the port number:

```
SET settings=D:\tomcat\conf\server.xml
FOR /F "eol=p tokens=1-2* delims==" %%A IN ('TYPE %settings% 2^> NUL ^| FINDSTR.exe /L /C:"\<Connector port\="') DO (
 SET PORT=%%B
 SET PORT=%PORT:" protocol=%
 SET PORT=%PORT:"=%

 goto :break
)
:break
pause
```

Thanks!

Comment: so always the first one is the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

SET settings=D:\tomcat\conf\server.xml
FOR /F "eol=p tokens=1-2* delims==" %%A IN ('TYPE %settings% 2^> NUL ^| FINDSTR.exe /L /C:"\<Connector port\="') DO (
 echo %%B
 goto :break
)
:break
pause
```

If the first node is always the correct one you can break the for loop with goto